# Why can't a function in a block-level scope change a formal parameter?

Tags: javascript

```
;(function(a){
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // 1
})(1)

;(function(){
    var a = 0
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // function a(){}
})()
```

Why can't a function in a block-level scope change a formal parameter?

Comment: Conditional `function` declarations are an icky edge case to begin with and handled differently in different engines.

Comment: @deceze: yeah, weird. I tried to check what you said. Using console tool on all browsers, they all say `1` for the first and `ƒ a(){}` for the second. But nodejs and Tampermonkey print `1` and `0` :)

Comment: Why don't you use `a = function () {};`? This prints `f(){}` for case 1.

Comment: Working on a long answer because this is interesting... coming soon.

Comment: @Chad Moore: Function arguments behave more like variables defined with let than vars? I may not think so； `(function(b){function b(){};console.log(b)})(1)`  b final output as a function,if `(function(){let b =1 ; function b(){};console.log(b)})(1)`  Will report an error ， 'b' has already been declared

Comment: I didn't say they behaved JUST like them, but more like them in that JavaScript in non-strict mode will not allow your conditional function declaration to overwrite either your function arguments or variables declared with 'let'.

Comment: Furthermore, in my post below, I made that vey point, that using 'let' will throw an error if you try to redefine it in the same scope.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you want to do this, but let's explore this for the sake of better understanding a corner case of JavaScript. Sometimes that helps us understand the fundamentals of the language better.

For sake of discussion, let's consider your two examples, as Case A and Case B, respectively:

```
// Case A - argument a is not overwritten
;(function(a){
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // 1
})(1)

// Case B - var a is overwritten
;(function(){
    var a = 0
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // function a(){}
})()
```

**Why a function declaration in block-level scope cannot change a formal parameter**

In JavaScript `var` does *not* have block scope, it has *functional* scope, so you cannot assume that every time you see `{ }` that it creates a scope for the vars declared within it. Basically, function blocks work differently than other blocks as used by conditions and iterations.

Recently, with [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/#let-const), block-scoped variables were introduced with the keywords `let` and `const`. Nevertheless, scoping is not straightforward in JS, so you must understand how different keywords create variables and how they are scoped within different block structures, and also how strict-mode affects that behavior.

As it turns out, Case B is a fluke and an accident of the way that `var` and `function () {}` declarations work in non-strict mode.

First, in all JavaScript (strict mode included), functions defined with function declarations, e.g. `function foo() {...}` are hoisted to the top of the current block-level scope! This means that, within scope, you can never overwrite a `var` by a function declaration.

```
// Case B modified
;(function(){
    console.log(a) // function a(){}
    var a = 0;  // overwrites value of 'a'
    function a(){}; // will be hoisted to top of block-level scope
    console.log(a) // 0
})()
```

Secondly, within conditional `if` blocks, function declarations are hoisted to the top of any block they are defined within, not the surrounding function block.

Third, in sloppy mode (non-strict), JavaScript, for function declarations defined with an `if` block will allow that value to overwrite the values of variables declared with `var` prior to that block.

```
// showing behavior of points #2 and #3:
;(function(){
    console.log(a); // undefined
    var a = 0;
    console.log(a); // 0
    if(true) {
       console.log(a); // function a(){...} - a() was hoisted to top of if block
       function a() {};
    })();
    console.log(a); // function a(){} - function declaration allowed to overwrite var declared above in surrounding function scope
})();
```

So, you've discovered a strange corner case where function declaration hoisting and scoping behave badly in non-strict mode. It won't do this in strict mode, see next section below on that.

Function arguments behave more like variables defined with `let` than `var`s, so that's why Case A doesn't behave like Case B. It's not so much that block-level scope function declarations cannot change a formal parameter as it is that it just shouldn't do that anyway, even for vars. Case A is how it ought to behave.

Note, that if you use `let` instead of `var` things behave more consistently, even in sloppy mode:

```
// Case B using 'let' instead
;(function(){
    let a = 0;
    console.log(a); // 0
    if(true) {
        console.log(a); // function a(){}
        function a() {};
    }
    console.log(a); 0
})();
```

Also, `let` just behaves better in general, for instance, even in sloppy mode, attempting to redefine a variable already declared with `let` is not allowed:

```
// just try this!
let a = 0;
function a() {} // this will throw a syntax error
```

**Difference between Node and Browser? No. It's about strict mode.**

Some commenters noted a difference between Node.js and JavaScript in a browser on this issue.  The claim was that:

```
// in a browser
console.log(a) // Case A: 1
console.log(a) // Case B: function a(){}
// in node
console.log(a) // Case A: 1
console.log(a) // Case B: 0
```

But in fact, I just tested with both Codepen in a browser, and with Node (8.11.3 and 10.5.0) on my local, and both returned these results:

```
 // in Node and browser
console.log(a) // Case A: 1
console.log(a) // Case B: function a(){}
```

However, when you set the `use strict` directive, then you get the following results, but the same in both Node and browser:

```
 // with 'use strict, in Node and browser
console.log(a) // Case A: 1
console.log(a) // Case B: 0
```

**Recommendations on Conditional Function Declarations**

Basically, I would not do this, unless my function always returned a function. In other words, I wouldn't write a function or method, in most cases, to at times return a primitive value and other times return a function.

But let's assume you wanted to do that. Then as a matter of course, I would always:

- use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)
- use `let` and `const` instead of `var` [See section 'Variables' here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

And I would, in this case, not use a function declaration, but assign a function expression to my variable instead:

```
;(function(){
    let a = 0;
    console.log(a); // 0
    if(true) {
        console.log(a); // 0
        a = function () {}; // assign 'a' the value of the function
    }
    console.log(a); // function () { ... }
})();
```

For my own sake, I created a Codepen to help with all of this: https://codepen.io/mrchadmoore/pen/jpEKaR?editors=0012

Answer (score 1):

The better question is why **can** you change a var-declared name? And the answer is because backward compatibility with old non-standard browser behavior.

If you declare the variable with "let" instead of "var", you get 0.

```
;(function(){
    let a = 0
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // 0
})()
```

Or if you use "var" but also "use strict", you get 0.

```
;(function(){
    "use strict";
    var a = 0
    if(true){
        function a(){}
    }
    console.log(a) // 0
})()
```

So a var-declared name in a non-strict environment is the special case.

Here's the relevant portion of the spec if you're interested.
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics